# C# Hill-Cipher last 3 characters wrong, rest correct

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to implement the Hill-Cipher in C# and have run into something weird that I can't figure out. My Code looks like this:

```
public string Encrypt(string plaintext)
{
    plaintext = plaintext.ToLower();
    plaintext = plaintext.Replace(" ", "");

    string ciphertext = null;
    int[,] keyMatrix = new int[,] { { 13, 7, 16 }, { 19, 4, 8 }, { 4, 22, 7 } }; //Sample Matrix, should later be given as "key"
    int[] valueOfCharMatrix = new int[plaintext.Length + (plaintext.Length % 3)], cipherValueOfCharMatrix = new int[plaintext.Length + (plaintext.Length % 3)];

    //Convert full plaintext to it's INT value
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.Length; i++)
    {
        valueOfCharMatrix[i] = (byte)(plaintext[i] - 'a');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < valueOfCharMatrix.Length - (valueOfCharMatrix.Length % 3); i += 3)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            //Matrix multiplication, keyMatrix * valueOfCharMatrix mod 26
            cipherValueOfCharMatrix[i + j] = (valueOfCharMatrix[i] * keyMatrix[j, 0] +
                                          valueOfCharMatrix[i + 1] * keyMatrix[j, 1] +
                                          valueOfCharMatrix[i + 2] * keyMatrix[j, 2]) % 26; //i % 3 works
        }
    }

    //Convert cipher INTs to chars
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherValueOfCharMatrix.Length; i++)
    {
        ciphertext += (char)(cipherValueOfCharMatrix[i] + 'a');
    }

    return ciphertext;
}
```

If I run the program, encrypt something and then check it against the results of these two sites: [dcode.fr](https://www.dcode.fr/hill-cipher) and [cryptool.org](https://www.cryptool.org/en/cto-ciphers/hill). What I find every time is that the last three chars are always different but the rest match. Here is what I mean: [Result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1SQX.png), [result of dcode.fr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTUmZ.png), [result of cryptool.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zx4p.png)
As you can see, the two sites deliver the same results, which only differ from mine by the last three chars.

The code above is from a C#-Class which is part of a Visual Studio Project, you can find the source [here](https://gitlab.com/noelkra/onyx-encrypt/).

Comment: That code doesn't compile, abcRegular and tempString aren't declared.

Comment: @SteveJ abcRegular is declared outside the function I posted here and tempString was accidentaly removed, I corrected it.

Comment: Ah, ok. This won't fix your problem, but might simplify your code: You don't need that abcRegular, you can convert the plain text to integers by subtracting 'a'. E.g. valueOfCharMatrix[i] = (byte)(plainText[i] - 'a');

Comment: And the reverse at the end: cipherText += (char)(cipherValueOfCharMatrix[i] + 'a');

Comment: @SteveJ Nice thanks alot! Changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code handles most of the ciphertext correctly, so it leads to the thought that the issue is how you handle the last characters.

Notice that you (correctly) add characters to the plaintext to have a length that is divisible by 3. The characters you add are `A`s, simply because the array is initialized by zeros.

However, the two websites you linked to choose instead to fill the vectors with `Z`s, i.e. the integer value 25. This accounts for the difference you see between your code and the websites.

```
//Convert full plaintext to it's INT value
for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < abcRegular.Length; j++)
    {
        if (abcRegular[j] == plaintext[i])
        {
            valueOfCharMatrix[i] = j;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = plaintext.Length; i < valueOfCharMatrix.Length; i++)
{
    valueOfCharMatrix[i] = abcRegular.Length - 1;
}
```

Another issue I found is that you add 3 more characters even if the plaintext length is divisible by 3. You might want to fix that.

Comment: Thanks alot. The adding 3 characters was because I tried to make the encryption loop 3 times more, because I thought the last chars were not beeing worked on. Code changed accordingly.